# How to make a button act like a link to refresh a page?

Tags: jquery

I have a snippet of JQuery code that should refresh the page when a user clicks on the "Discard" button/link. Its like this:

```
$('#Discard').click(function(event) {
        window.location();
        event.preventdefault();
    });
```

If I place a link on my site like this:

```
<a href="javascript:;" id="Discard">Discard</a>
```

The the JQuery does its job perfectly.

But if I do this instead then it fails and nothing happens when I click on the button:

```
<input type="button" name="Discard" id="Discard" value="Discard"/>
```

I'd prefer to use a button because it will be placed right next to a submit button. How can I make this work?

Comment: maybe you just need `location.reload(true);` http://jsfiddle.net/2cb8dbrk/

Comment: you can use an empty button but you need to use type=submit

Comment: @RST : I disagree check http://jsfiddle.net/20ejvgcy/ and http://jsfiddle.net/2cb8dbrk/ for what it matters

Comment: What I meant was, when you use a separate form tag for the discard button, with no jquery attached it will automatically refresh. @volume one Are you sure your button is inside form tags?

Comment: @JFK using location.reload() reloads the page and resubmits the form again. Using window.location() seems to do a redirect so you can refresh the page without resubmitting the form which is what I needed.

Comment: @RST the discard button is right next to the submit button within the same form.

Comment: You never mentioned you have a form to submit, only a button to refresh the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give this a try for your button refresh

```
    $('#Discard').click(function(event) {
                var currentURL = document.URL;
        window.location.href = currentURL;
    });
```

Comment: Thanks Bob, it does exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#discard').click(function (event) {
        location.reload(true);
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" name="discard" id="discard" value="Discard"/>
```

Comment: a bit opportunistic, read comments http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25633297/how-to-make-a-button-act-like-a-link-to-refresh-a-page#comment40050277_25633297

Comment: I didn't read the comments though. Already used it a lot of time.

Comment: well, it's a good idea to read the comments (and previous answers) before answering, otherwise you give the wrong impression

Comment: Ok thank you for advice I'll surely keep in mind next time. But I must say you can't vote down an answer on your assumptions. Its discouraging.

Comment: Yes I can, because it discourages plagiarism ;)

Comment: if that's what you think, Sure :)

Comment: This doesn't do what I need exactly. Yes it does make the button refresh the page, but it also causes the form to be resubmitted. Using window.location removes the persistent form post hence I was using that.